# Play 2 transaction per request

Tags: sql, scala, transactions, anorm, playframework-2.3

Most convenient transaction management for me is using one optional transaction for entire http request. This means that first SQL statement should retrieve connection from the pool, start the transaction and after request processing finished, transaction should be commited (or rolled back if exception was thrown) and connection should be closed. Of course more fine-grained transaction management must be possible if needed.

Does Play 2 supports this out of the box? I probably can implement it myself, but I'm looking for ready solution.

I looked at DB object, but it seems that DB.withConnection uses new connection (and transaction) every time.

I'm using Scala and Anorm db library, if it matters.

Comment: You need to specify at least which DB approach you use and in which language (Java/Scala)

Comment: I'm using Scala with Anorm db library.

Comment: I expected more general solution without need to alter controllers, but probably it doesn't exists. I'll check your response.

Comment: Using the `Transaction` action I defined as about as general as it can get. If you want the transaction for each controller function, then it would make sense to provision it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB.withTransaction` is what you'll want. Just like `DB.withConnection`, it will provision a single connection from the connection pool for all of the contained SQL functions. Since you want to use one transaction per request, it seems like it would make the most sense to call it within the controller function, and require all of your model functions to have an implicit connection parameter.

Model:

```
object Product {

    def checkInventory(id: Long)(implicit c: Connection): Int = SQL(...)

    def decrementInventory(id: Long, quantity: Int)(implicit c: Connection): Boolean = SQL(...)

}

object Cart {

    def addItem(id: Long, quantity: Int)(implicit c: Connection): Boolean = SQL(...)

}
```

Controller function:

```
def addToCart(id: Long, quantity: Int) = Action {

    DB.withTransaction{ implicit connection =>
       if(Product.checkInventory(id) >= quantity && Product.decrementInventory(id, quantity)) {

        Cart.addItem(id, quantity)
        ....
       } else {
           BadRequest
       }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** This is clearly not a logically sound shopping cart transaction, and just a simple illustration of using database transactions.

Following `Action` composition examples in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition), you can make a special `Transaction` action that provisions the transaction for each request automatically:

```
object Transaction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
        DB.withTransaction{implicit connection => block(request)}
    }
}
```

And use it just like `Action`:

```
def addToCart(id: Long, quantity: Int) = Transaction {
    Product.checkInventory(id)

    ...
}
```

**Pitfalls**: Providing a transaction per request in this way is convenient, especially when most of your controller functions are supposed to represent atomic actions. However, this method will not release the `Connection` from the transaction until the `Result` has been returned to the user. This means that if you are returning a large data set that takes a long time to serve/render for the client, you'll be holding onto the connection for that much longer than you really need it.

Comment: Is it good to have all DB.withConnection in action? Can you accomplish better layered design with less verbose with something like cake pattern or DaoManager?